# Sieve of Eratosthenes C++ Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So, I've been working through a problem in Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practices Using C++ for my own benefit, and this problem has stumped me for a couple of days now.

I'm supposed to implement the classic Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm with the tools learned by chapter 4 (that's not a lot) and this is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p = 2;
    int n = 0;
    vector<int> nums{ 1, 1 };

    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 1:\n";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
        nums.push_back(0);

    while (p < sqrt(n))
    {
        for (int i = 2; (i*p) <= n; ++i)
        {
            nums[i*p] = 1;
        }

        for (int i = (p+1); i <= n; ++i)
        {
            if (nums[i] == 0)
            {
                p = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if (nums[i] == 0)
            cout << i << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is SOOO close to working but no cigar. It only prints the prime numbers after and including 5, it does not print 2 or 3. I know that the problem is due to the fact that my marking loop is marking nums[2] and nums[3], so I tried to add the following line of code to insure that 2 and 3 were unmarked, because they were used as the p starting values:

```
nums[p] = 0;
```

I put that line in-between the two for-loops nested within the while-loop. I have no idea how, but that somehow causes an infinite loop that I've tried for hours to fix. I'm really at my wit's end here.

NOTE: I've been testing this with n = 23.

Comment: because your marker `for` loop starts at `0`, each time you find a prime, it marks `0` and `p` as non prime as well. In your case, since `5>sqrt(23)`, the marker loop doesn't get run for any prime larger than `3`, that's why you get those primes back, but `2` and `3` are the unlucky ones :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Unfortunately, making my marker loop start at i = 2 also gets me into an infinite loop!

Comment: When you make an important correction, like the `i=0` changed to `i=2`, and the code is still not working, please edit your original post to show the version you now want help with.  Do not just tell us you corrected that bug, leaving us to guess whether you corrected it correctly.

Comment: I think `nums{ 1 1 }` means length of 1 and value 1.  But I suspect you intended elements 0 and 1 to both be 1.

Comment: That's because in the loop after your marker loop, you are starting to look for the first prime from `0`, which is going to be always be `2`. So you are always marking the multiples of `2` and never getting a `p` that is larger than `2`. In your second `for` loop, start your search for the next prime from `p + 1`.

Comment: @triple_rr You should write your answers as an answer.

Comment: @AlanStokes thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that :-)

Comment: @triple_rr That fixed the problem! I then tested with the value 46, to find that it printed 46 at the end of the list of primes, when it clearly isn't a prime. To solve that issue I changed the condition in the marker loop from '<' to '<=' and that fixed the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after fixing your first loop starting point, the issue is the next loop.

Because the next loop always starts at `0` and looks for the next prime number, it is going to always find `2`, and that will cause an infinite loop.

To solve this issue, start your search for the next prime, from the previous value:

```
    for(int i = p + 1; i <= n; ++i)
```